# Are there any sefarim about Melech David

Tags: jewish-books, tanach, names, king-david

Today we named our son David at the Brit Mila and I realized I wanted to learn more about King David. Outside of Tehilim and Shmuel I&II (which are understandably the core sources), does anyone have a safer about David they would recommend? Ideally one in English. Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I know there are plenty of peirushim on nach, midrashim, talmud and more. I am not sure about a David sefer, sorry. But you got me thinking. What would it include? Just David in Nach? Tehillim? His purposerfully controversial lineage & origin with his mother, Ruth & Boaz, Yehuda & Tamar and Lot's daughters? Laws of and general info on kings? A little or alot on moshiach who descends from David and who is most commonly reffered to as David or ben David?.. I guess one could keep adding more and more to my list here and I guess it is totally up to the author. Oh and Mazel Tov.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it's true there's a lot of different potential material. I think it would be interesting to combine history and a deeper dive into his character and middot. I know there are secular books on King David but they analyze David in a literal way based on their understanding of what's written about him in Shmuel.

Comment: A follow up question would be a good sefer that explains tehilim (or at least some of them). I find that many of the tehilim are hard to penetrate. I have the artscroll version which adds some detail but not enough imo.